# Zend Framework. controller before action method

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, zend-framework2, zend-form

In Zend Framework 2 in many action of controller I have this lines:

```
$form = new Tmp_Form_form();
$form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost());
$data = $form->getValues();
```

In order to have DRY code, is possible to use a method like `before_filter` or `before_actions` like Ruby on Rails?

Comment: Maybe this help http://stackoverflow.com/q/18698397/949273

Comment: While it is code duplication, it is good kind. By trying to move that logic where it does not belong you will create unneeded entanglement.